# Battery life decreased after upgrade to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, power-management, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why does my computer get less battery life with Ubuntu compared to Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows)

After upgrading from Ubuntu 10.10, my battery life has decreased dramatically.

There was a bug in Ubuntu 10.10 where the `Load Balancing Tick` and `Kworker` would interrupt and wake-up the cpu too much, and this wasn't normal. I applied a gnome-power-manager fix back then, [following this question,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23404/laptop-battery-life-drastically-decreased-compared-to-windows-7) which leads to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/524281), and battery life increased to 3.5 hours.

I'm getting around two hours of battery-life in Natty, and calling Intel's powertop reveals that this bug is back. Is there a fix for Natty yet?

I have a Core 2 Duo ULV, Thinkpad Edge 13

Comment: Have you tried using the applications "Jupiter", or "PowerTop"?

Comment: My Eee 1005 which was getting 8 hours is only getting something like 3 to 5 hours now, it is horrible. Would going back to Maverick or installing Debian be the only option?

Comment: @queueoverflow, you might want to try the temporary workaround suggested in fossfreedom's answer.