# Does Unity on UNR provide power savings over the traditional UI?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, power-management

I have recently installed UNB on my Atom-based netbook ( side-by-side with the default Windows 7 Starter ), and I'm very disappointed with the default interface. I really like the design, it looks tailor-made for netbooks - but it is *so* limited ! ( no shortcuts on the sidebar, or on the desktop; generally confusing )

I'm considering a switch to the traditional user interface, the only thing which would make me stick with Unity is if it would provide power savings over the standard UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since UNR was discontinued with Ubuntu 11.04 (there's only a "desktop edition" instead), I assume you are talking about default Unity interface - unless, of course, you use Ubuntu 10.10 or 10.04.

Anyway, there's no reason to stick with Unity for power savings, Unity depends on hardware accelerated Compiz which tends to be quite power hungry.

If a battery lifetime is a big concern for you, you should even consider using an older release than 11.04 due to [power regression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38117/battery-life-decreased-after-upgrade-to-11-04) in recent versions of Linux kernel.