# Do I need to add a boot parameter to work around this kernel power bug on a Sony Vaio VPC-EH1S0E?

Tags: grub2, kernel, power-management, acpi, pcie

If i with

```
dmesg | grep -i aspm
```

have this:

```
[    0.503709] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.673564] ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM
```

I've read that is a bug in the Linux kernel and I've also read that there is a workaround but I don't know if I have to apply this workaround or not.

**So do I have to add `pcie_aspm=force` to grub2?**

Comment: see similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38117/battery-life-decreased-after-upgrade-to-11-04/38194#38194

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i've add "pcie_aspm=force" and i've gained 20 minutes :)
So if someone have a **Sony Vaio VPC-EH1S0E** can easily add the parameter to the grub line in this way:

```
sudo nano -w /etc/default/grub
```

and where there is this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

change it into:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

You can also check the power consumption with powertop:

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

and then:
    `sudo powertop`

My battery consumption was decreased from 20.1W to 15.3W :)

Comment: This may work for some, and others have the same problem as me. See this comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/linux-power-regression-overheating-problem-on-thinkpad-fixed/#comment-361808547 As you can see, at first they said I was nuts, a week later people asked me if there was any way to fix their batteries.

Answer (score -1):

Andrew Wyatt's blog post [About the Kernel 3.0 "Power Regression" Myth](https://web.archive.org/web/20120718035639/http://www.fewt.com/2011/09/about-kernel-30-power-regression-myth.html) explains well about kernel regression and aspm issue. May be it would be of some help.

Comment: i've read it...so it seem that i have to add the line to grub right?

Comment: If it says so..