# Can RC6 (GPU power management) status be changed during runtime?

Tags: i915

I am considering to try what is mentioned here - [Battery life decreased after upgrade to 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38117/battery-life-decreased-after-upgrade-to-11-04/38194#38194) - concerning minimizing power  consumption.

For example I see that in my case - i915.i915_enable_rc6=0 by issuing the following command cat /sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_rc6 .

Would it be possible to switch it to 1 after booting?

If yes, how can we do that?

Comment: Have you tried TLP ? Google it and there are many links .

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
sudo modinfo i915 | grep "i915_enable_rc6"
```

You would see this:

```
    parm:           i915_enable_rc6:Enable power-saving render C-state 6. 
    Different stages can be selected via bitmask values (0 = disable; 1 = enable rc6; 
2 = enable deep rc6; 4 = enable deepest rc6).
    For example, 3 would enable rc6 and deep rc6, and 7 would enable everything.
    default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)
```

I think that answers your question : )

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I had the same question, and I believe the answer is **no, you can't change the parameter at runtime**.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough to elaborate on this, but I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123050/275183) that might be helpful.

You can, however, [change the parameter temporarily at boot time](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) if what you're trying to do is test the change before making it permanent (which is what I've been trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps u could take a look in [cpufrequtils](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils) (if u have prerequisites).
TLP also works, but not so specific.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1187012)